# Invalid "safe harbour" decision - what has changed?

Tags: united-states, law, european-union, privacy

The international [Safe Harbor Privacy Principles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Safe_Harbor_Privacy_Principles) were declared invalid by the European Court of Justice [in October 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Safe_Harbor_Privacy_Principles#Citizen_complaint_about_Facebook_data_safety).

Is it known whether the behavior of companies storing consumer data and transmitting them over the Atlantic has changed so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly no, see e.g. Facebook's [response to a demand and summons letter](http://www.forbes.com/sites/lisabrownlee/2015/12/15/facebook-threatened-with-lawsuit-over-eu-us-data-transfers-facebook-response/). There is a period of grace until January 31, 2016, and chances are a new agreement to replace Safe Harbor will be worked out until then – otherwise that is when there will be visible changes.

Never the less, big companies are increasingly building or expanding [European data centres](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/nov/10/microsoft-open-first-uk-data-centres-safe-harbour), e.g. Microsoft, Amazon and HP give customers the option of storing data in Europe.

If you take a look at the certified Safe Harbor companies, however, it becomes obvious that the dark figure of (smaller) companies storing data in the US must be way higher – but since they have operated illegally up until now, they're likely to also do so in the future, depending on how rigorously the data protection authorities will enforce.

[**Update 02/03/16:**](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/03/technology/us-europe-safe-harbor-data-deal.html) Privacy Shield will be the new agreement, based mainly on US guarantees to not give their intelligence agencies indiscriminate access to EU data.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a new agreement is legally possible unless PRISM is shut down completely and the FISA is closed.